# position the right hand edge of a string a certain distance from the centre of a page in CSS

Tags: css, positioning

name says it all, but I want to be able to position an element based on a defined distance from the page centre, but the measurement must be between the centre and right hand edge of the element.

is this possible?

Comment: `"between the the the centre"` - is that some kind of special super centre? I think I know what you're asking, but consider drawing a quick image so people are sure.

Comment: oooops, my bad. I just mean the centre of the parent element. The extra the's were due to excessive morning caffeine, I'd say.

Comment: Is it allowed to specify a fixed width on the element that is being positioned? What context is the element being placed in? Should it appear on top of other elements? (I'd still like a picture or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want (*if i understand correctly*)

```
position:absolute;
right:50%;
margin-right:-<distance_you_want>px;
```

parent element should be positioned as well (*`absolute` or `relative`*)

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/jD443/ (*vertical line at center of box for illustration*)

Comment: but this requires me to know the distance, I don't know the width of the element, and therefore can't know the position of its right hand edge.

Comment: @Mild, no it doesn't. The distance i mention is the distance from the center. I you put 0 the right edge of the element will be at the center of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

[**See example of the following →**](http://jsfiddle.net/QJJWK/1/)

You'll need an extra wrapper, but hit can be accomplished with a child that has `position:relative; margin:0 auto; width:1px` and a grandchild that has `position:absolute; right:XXpx;` where XX is the distance to the right of the center that you desire.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <div id="kid">40px right of center ==&gt;</div>
    </div>
</div>

#parent { 
    width:400px; height:200px;
}
#child {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:1px; height:200px;
}
#kid {
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute; right:-40px;
    width:180px;
}
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/QJJWK/1/)